# Find and replace expression with notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I've need to serch with notepad ++ this word:

```
!fieldname,
```

and replace with

```
dr("fieldname"),
```

where `"fieldname"` contain any alphabetic characters, digits and undescores.

Temporally I've find this solution, but it don't replace underscores and digits:

```
find: (!)([A-z]+)(,)   - !asdasdsd,
replace: dr\(\"\2\"\)\3 - dr("asdasdsd"),
```

Comment: Did you try using `\w` instead of `[A-z]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find

```
!(\w+),
```

replace with

```
dr\("\1"\),
```

Answer (score 1):

! ([a-zA-Z_\d]+) 
dr('\1')
But you should ust double qoites as you want.

Answer (score 0):

find: `\!([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\,`

replace: `dr\("\1"\),`